# How to provide documentation for WCF clients?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, documentation

I created a web service in WCF and published it on a web server but when I tried to consume it in a console app, the documentation I put in to the web service class/methods are not available in the console app. The WSDL file doesn't have them either.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, what are my options of providing documentation for clients?

Comment: Did you enabled the serviceMetadata? Can you post the configuration of the wcf service(app.config with serviceModel section)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) might do want you want.

If you are looking to implement a custom solution, the MSDN article [Custom WSDL Publication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a good starting point.